# How do I programmatically select a tab on a .NET CF TabControl?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, tabcontrol

With the .NET Framework 2.0/3.5 TabControl, I can programmatically select a tab using the SelectedTab property as shown in the code below:

```
//toggles between tabPage1 and tabPage2
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1)
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
    else
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
}
```

The .NET **Compact** Framework TabControl doesn't have a SelectedTab property like its .NET Framework counterpart.  So, how do I select a tab programmatically?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

TabControl.SelectedIndex

Comment: I found that when the TabControl is selected, it does not display correctly.  It seems that after selecting a TabControl it is useful to Refresh it, so, where the TabControl is called TabForm and has mutliple Tabs, this might be:
`    Me.TabForm.SelectedIndex = 0
     Me.TabPg0.Refresh       'Where TabPg0 is the name of the Tab at Index 0`

Comment: What worked for me was to set "IsSelected" on the newest TabItem and then use UpdateLayout() on the TabControl:((TabItem)tabControl.Items[tabControl.Items.Count - 1]).IsSelected = true; tabControlCode.UpdateLayout();

Answer (score 0):

I programmed this code.  When click on tabPage1, then the program will close:

```
private void tabControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Logout!");
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that when the TabControl is selected, it does not display correctly.  It seems that after selecting a TabControl it is useful to Refresh it.  So, where the TabControl is called TabForm and has multiple Tabs, this might be:

```
 Me.TabForm.SelectedIndex = 0
 Me.TabPg0.Refresh            'Where TabPg0 is the name of the Tab at Index 0
```

Answer (score -1):

in .Net 4 can use

```
if (tabControl1.Controls[5] == tabControl1.SelectedTab)
                MessageBox.Show("Tab 5 Is Selected");
```

OR

```
if ( tabpage5 == tabControl1.SelectedTab)
         MessageBox.Show("Tab 5 Is Selected");
```

Comment: This question was not about .NET 4; it was about .NET CF.

Answer (score -3):

WPF code, try this:

```
if (tabControl1.SelectedValue == tabPage1)
    tabControl1.SelectedValue = tabPage2;
else
    tabControl1.SelectedValue = tabPage1;
```

Comment: WPF and the Compact framework don't mix, don't they...? (Or did I miss something?)

Comment: Plus, this is exactly what the question says does not work: a working alternative was called for.

Comment: Sorry, I did miss the Compact statement but I believe SelectedValue will work in the compact framework, it is missing SelectedTab.